# cancelling alarms

Tags: android, alarm

i'm new to android and java programming and i have an application that fires multiple alarms and repeats them every day. it is working fine but my problem is when i delete an alarm it keeps firing the next day. they told me to use cancel method and i created this function:

```
public void deleteReminder(Long reminderId){
    Intent d = new Intent(mContext, Daily_OnAlarmReceiver.class);
    d.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID_DAILY, (long)reminderId);

    int Daily_requestCode = reminderId.intValue(); 


    PendingIntent pid = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, Daily_requestCode, d, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT); 

    mAlarmManager.cancel(pid);
}
```

my set Reminder function as follows:

```
public void setReminder(Long reminderId, Calendar when) {

        Intent i = new Intent(mContext, Daily_OnAlarmReceiver.class);
        i.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID_DAILY, (long)reminderId); 
        int Daily_requestCode = reminderId.intValue(); 

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, Daily_requestCode, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT); 
        mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
}
```

both of them are placed in the AlarmManager.java file.

the following code is in another java file which deletes the alarm from the list only but it doesnt prevent the system from firing the alarm:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_delete:

            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
               mDbHelper.deleteDailyReminder(info.id);
               fillData();
               return true;
        }
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
```

my question is how to call this `new Daily_ReminderManager(this).deleteReminder(mRowId);`  in the previous code so the reminder will be deleted from the list and from the alarm manager too.

and i'm wondering if my first code is correct

Answer (score 0):

In order to cancel the alarm  `Intents` must match as defined by [`filterEquals(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals%28android.content.Intent%29).

This means the intents action, data, type, class, and categories must be the same. Extra data is not used in this comparison.

Comment: how to use filterEquals in my case?

Comment: You don't. This is what AlarmManager uses when comparing intents in order to cancel them.

Comment: what should i do in my code in order to make the deleted alarm from the list to be cancelled from the service too?